# How to profile into Java serialization in JProfiler

Tags: jprofiler

Using JProfiler 7.1 (also tried 7.0) I cannot profile into Java serialization.

I have removed all filters, using dynamic, estimate CPU, profiling.

It seems like it does not profile into any JDK methods?

Not attaching to an existing JVM, JProfiler is launching the test.

Windows, 64bit, jdk 1.6